# ElasticSearch: Is there a way to apply two scripts in the same query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to build a query based on two script filters, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried using nesting (following the example in the doc), but keep getting a syntax error:

```
QueryParsingException[[my_index] [_na] filter malformed, no field after start_object
```

The query is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query":{
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "things.type:1 AND things.status:1"
                }
            }, 
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                   "path": "obj",
                   "_cache": true, 
                   "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "script": "doc['things.type'].values.size() == 1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "script": "obj['other_things.key'].values.size() >= 1"
                                }
                            ]
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could just pull the records from the first script (`"script": "doc['things.type'].values.size() == 1"`) and iterate over the list in Python (sing `pyelasticsearch` to execute these queries), but it seems that elastic search should be able to do this.

Comment: Note that by doing this, you are loading all the values of the fields into memory, just to get the count. You should consider adding the size of the lists at index-time, so you can simply filter on its size.  That can save you a *lot* of memory. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested objects, so you need two separated nested filters.  Each nested filter applies to a single document, so you can't access different documents in one nested clause.  You can have as many filters as you need, connected with and:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "things.type:1 AND things.status:1"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "other_things",
                "filter": {
                  "script": {
                    "script": "doc['other_things.key'].values.size() >= 1"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "things",
                "filter": {
                  "script": {
                    "script": "doc['things.type'].values.size() == 1"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite, I should have been more specific. `things` and `other_things` are both attributes of `master_thing`.

Comment: I edited to use two separate nested filters, one for each nested type.